# error: accessing build database "/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/build.db": disk I/O error

Tags: ios, swift

In our project, we are building universal frameworks and we are able to generate iOS SDK without issue and we are able to integrate without error. But while building iOS SDK (Xcode-> Product-> Build)we are getting the above error and get Build Failed. How to fix this?
I will add the run script here.

```
# Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.
######################
# Options
######################

REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER=true

FRAMEWORK_NAME="XXXX"

SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"

FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

PROJECTNAME="XXXX"

######################
# Clean
######################

xcodebuild clean -workspace "${PROJECTNAME}.xcworkspace" -scheme "${PROJECTNAME}" 

######################
# Build Frameworks
######################

xcodebuild BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode -workspace "${PROJECTNAME}.xcworkspace" -scheme "${PROJECTNAME}" -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator" 2>&1

xcodebuild BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode -workspace "${PROJECTNAME}.xcworkspace" -scheme "${PROJECTNAME}" -sdk iphoneos -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos" 2>&1


######################
# Create directory for universal
######################

rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

mkdir "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

mkdir "${FRAMEWORK}"


######################
# Copy files Framework
######################

cp -r "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/." "${FRAMEWORK}"
```

Comment: Save your disk data in case it is a hardware problem. You can clean project.

Comment: We have tried to clean project and derived data every time. But it still throwing an error? Any fix for these @PtitXav

Comment: Did you check that the file build.db is there ? Try to make a copy of it, then move it somewhere else and then try to delete it. It may be corrupted.

Comment: yeah!!! tried still getting an issue.